# Starting application pool concurrently causes error related to maximum number of concurrent shells

Tags: shell, powershell, concurrency

I have a powershell script which can run asynchorusly to start multiple application pools.

But when i have a certain amount of app pools to start it throws the following error:

> The running command stopped because the preference variable
>   "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: [ServerX]
>   Connecting to remote server XXX failed with the following error
>   message : The WS-Management service cannot process the request. This
>   user has exceeded the maximum number of concurrent shells allowed for
>   this plugin. Close at least one open shell or raise the plugin quota
>   for this user. For more information, see the
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

The maximum shells per user is 10000.

It seems that there is more happening beneath the hood when appcmd runs but not sure how i can get around this issue

Any advice would be great

Below is the winrs config

```
Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
----            ----                           -------------   -----
System.String   AllowRemoteShellAccess                         true
System.String   IdleTimeout                                    7200000
System.String   MaxConcurrentUsers                             10
System.String   MaxShellRunTime                                2147483647
System.String   MaxProcessesPerShell                           25
System.String   MaxMemoryPerShellMB                            1024
System.String   MaxShellsPerUser                               10000
```

Comment: At the powershell command line type this and paste the results: `cd WSMan:\localhost\Shell` then `dir`.

Comment: Have added the results in the question. MAxshellsPerUser is high enough. I have investigated further and it happens when stopping existing app pools and also starting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd WSMan:\localhost\Shell
Set-Item .\MaxProcessesPerShell 10000
```

Comment: Will make that change and hopefully. Also need to see why it happens by increasing it

Comment: Is this on the remote server or the machine initiating the remote calls?

Comment: got it, it is on the server. The server I had a problem with would not accept the cd WSMan command until after a reboot

Comment: Do I have to restart anything for this change to apply?