# Powershell - Get MaxPasswordAge from multiple servers

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

PS Version: 5.0.10586.117

My requirement is to loop through a list of servers and using the "Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy". I want to produce a list that has the server name and the MaxPasswordAge.  I have verified that my credentials work on the remote serves.  I don't want to change the MaxPasswordAge, I just want to know what it is for the specified server.

```
Server Name             MaxPasswordAge
Server1.domain.com            90
Server2.domain.com           109
Server3.domain.com           109
```

The error that I frequently get is the following:

```
New-PSSession : [Server1.domain.com] Connecting to remote server Server1.domain.com failed with the following error message : The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The maximum number of concurrent shells for this user has been 
exceeded. Close existing shells or raise the quota for this user. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:4 char:12
+ $Install = New-PSSession -ComputerName $SServer -Credential $Cred
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -2144108123,PSSessionOpenFailed
VERBOSE: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
```

Here is the code I am using.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Should I use: `Get-ADFineGrainedPasswordPolicy -Filter {Name -like "*"}` instead?

```
$servers = get-content "C:\TEMP\servers.txt"
$Cred = Get-Credential
$Result = $()


ForEach ($Computer in $servers)
{

     Try
        {
             $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Cred
             $Result = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {param($RName) Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy -server $RName | Select $RName, maxpasswordage | Format-Table} -ErrorAction Stop -ArgumentList $Computer
             Remove-PSSession $Session

        }
          Catch
        {
            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
            Write-Verbose -Message $ErrorMessage -Verbose
        }   



}

$Result | Export-Csv "C:\TEMP\ServerMaxPWAge.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Isn't this a domain wide setting (unless using fine grained policies which don't showup as the default domain password policy)?

Comment: workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942139/starting-application-pool-concurrently-causes-error-related-to-maximum-number-of

Comment: Do you have preexisting sessions still lying around between calls? `get-pssession`

Comment: It "should" be domain wide, but some servers have different policies implemented.  Is there a reg key I could look for?

Comment: @Matt If I get that error, I usually kill my current ISE and start over.

Comment: Do your target servers have any procs of WsmProvHost running? You might have killed your PowerShell console but the session is still running.

Comment: -Matt I do not see what running on the target server.

Comment: @bluuf Yes it should be a domain setting, but different servers have different GPOs applied.